# Reversing an array (vector) using reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, c++17

I'm trying to improve my c++ knowledge using Edabit challenges and testing out 'new' functions. Current challenge wants us to write a function to reverse an array.
examples:

```
reverse([1, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ [4, 3, 2, 1]

reverse([9, 9, 2, 3, 4]) ➞ [4, 3, 2, 9, 9]

reverse([]) ➞ []
```

I tried to do this using reverse_iterator, but I have some odd result.

```cpp
std::vector<int> reverse(std::vector<int> arr) {
    std::vector<int> out;
    for(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator i = arr.rbegin(); i != arr.rend(); ++i)
    {
        out.push_back(arr[*i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

The result I get is the following:

```
FAILED: Expected: equal to [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
Actual: [ 0, 4, 3, 2 ]
```

First it seems like it was just one off, o I added 1 with rbegin() and rend as follows:

```
for(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator i = arr.rbegin() + 1; i != arr.rend() + 1; ++i)
```

And it seems that the first test passed, but following test seems way off:

```
FAILED: Expected: equal to [ 7, 6, 5 ]
Actual: [ 33, 0, 5 ]
```

I'm trying to understand how this reverse iterator is working, so please provide a solution and some clear explanation why the first test passed with the addition of 1 and why the second did not pass.

Comment: You could have simply used the 1 line solution of `return std::vector<int>(arr.rbegin(), arr.rend());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
for(std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator i = arr.rbegin(); i != arr.rend(); ++i)
{
    out.push_back(*i);
}
```

Iterator already gives you a value, not an index into a vector.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! so the first test passing with adding 1 was just coincidence?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in the subscript operator

```
out.push_back(arr[*i]);
              ^^^^^^^
```

does not make sense.

You mean

```
out.push_back( *i );
```

But in any case the function can be written better either like this to create a new reversed vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


std::vector<int> reverse( const std::vector<int> &v ) 
{
    std::vector<int> out;
    out.reserve( v.size() );

    for ( auto first = std::rbegin( v ), last = std::rend( v ); first != last; ++first )
    {
        out.push_back( *first );
    }

    return out;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto reversed_v = reverse( v );

    for ( const auto &item : reversed_v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4
```

Or like this to reverse a vector in place

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


void reverse( std::vector<int> &v ) 
{
    if ( not v.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto first = std::rbegin( v ), last = std::rend( v ); first < --last; ++first )
        {
            std::iter_swap( first, last );
        }
    }       
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    reverse( v );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4
```

Alternatively there are corresponding standard algorithms `std::reverse_copy` and `std::reverse` that you can use instead.

Comment: @Aconcagua It is a reserved alternative representation of the operator !.

Comment: I know... Just like `or` can be used instead of `||` or `bitand` instead of `&`. It's just so unusual to see – actually haven't ever seen them really being used before – and don't take it as criticism :).

Answer (score 1):

Prefer algorithms in the standard library to hand crafted loops as much as possible because:
1) they are more expressive;
2) they are likely to be more efficient.

```
std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Just include the 'algorithm' header to use std::reverse.